# Add on click listener to multiple buttons?

Tags: java, android

I know for 1 button it is:

```
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do stuff here
    }
});
```

What if I have multiple buttons? Is this a general method for when any button is pressed?

Comment: I would recommend you learn Java basics.

Comment: No, each button has its own listener

Comment: What is your problem more specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an anonymous class, you could implement View.OnClickListener in an inner class, instantiate it, and use it for all buttons like this; where `handleButton1/2()` are methods inside your parent activity.

```
private class MyEventListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1_id:
            handleButton1();
            break;
            case R.id.button2_id:
            handleButton2();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside main activity onCreate():

```
OnClickListener mMyEventListener = new MyEventListener();
button1.setOnClickListener(mMyEventListener);
button2.setOnClickListener(mMyEventListener);
```

I like this because I can group buttons with similar behavior within the case block, or I can implement multiple interfaces on the same object so all of my UI interaction/callbacks go to one easy to keep track of location, rather than a ton of duplicated code in the form of dozens of anonymous listener classes.  For example, I can extend `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` if I have a listview and pass `mMyEventListener` to `ListView.setOnItemClick`.

Answer (score 0):

Each button has its own listener but of course you can call a commons method from all of the listeners in the same class

e.g.

```
 Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    //Do stuff here
    doStuff (v);
   }
 });
```

Comment: "Each button has its own listener" Not necessarily, they store just a reference to an object implementing the specific listener interface which _could_ be an instance of an anonymous class as in your code but doesn't have to (see @nexus_2006's answer).